# Is there any mention about Bhanamati in Puranas?

Tags: scripture, puranas

I was watching Ramanand Sagar Shree Krishna. I found some incidents which I didn't knew. 
For eg. Krishna went to Yamlok to revive Punardatta son of Sandipani Muni for Guru Dakshina

But on the context of story related to Pradyumna. They showed that Pradyumna mother Bhanamati (who took Pradyumna from fish ) was apsara named Padmini in previous birth and had gained Rasayan Vidya and Maya vidya from Lord Vishnu and due to unfair use of these got a curse that she will be born in Asura kul. And in this birth used same Rasayan Vidya to make Pradyumna youth instantly.

I think that story about Rasayan Vidya may be from Serial writer may be not.

I just want to know that is there any mention of Padmini apsara or Bhanamati in any Puranas ?

Edit :-
Shree Krishna Playlist - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-4lIp0mLzCa8QW9aDGoAC0Mb997HSFvs (In this playlist Pradyuman part is mentioned in video title which ranges from video 49 to 64 or part 55 to part 70)

The history of Bhanamati is explained in part 61 (Praduman part 7) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j35rwRHcA_M&list=PL-4lIp0mLzCa8QW9aDGoAC0Mb997HSFvs&index=56&t=2570s from 41:21 time

Comment: As per [Bhagavata Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35191/12304) and [Shiva Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24644/12304), she was Kamadeva's wife Rati..

Comment: @YDS Yes I have read that version. In that version it was Mayavati (Rati incarnation) who took Pradyumna. But the version which was shown in Serial is completely different. In Serial Mayavati was Sambara's wife. She wasn't incarnation of Rati and neither was Bhanamati.

Comment: Can u pls mention episode number/link?

Comment: @YDS I have mentioned link and episode number. Since Pradyuman part is extended over total 16 episodes. I have pointed out that specific video and time where Bhanamati identity is explained.