# What does Hinduism say about romantic love between man and woman?

Tags: women, sex, men, kama, love

What does Hinduism say about romantic love between man and woman ? Is it some illusion(maya) or Is it divine ?

Even Vishnu , Shiva and Krishna have spouses and romance certainly exists between them.

But there is another factor that needs to be noted- Many homosexual people are also involved in romantic love indicating romance **might** have its roots in lust (kaam).
It indicates **maybe** romantic love has nothing to do with opposite sex.

Comment: Don't equate humans to god..their love is always divine and we cannot explain them...Ex- Shiva ji burnt Manmatha but at the same time loves Parvati ji nd Sati ji. So divine love does not have Kama.

Comment: @LSSJBroly True , this is why in human beings we can find many couples who were in romantic love break-up after sometime. But Vishu-Lakshmi , Radha-Krishna and Shiva-Parvati are eternal couples.

Comment: [Related](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24634/what-is-story-behind-shiva-burnt-kamadeva-manmadha-to-ashes)